# To iterate a html svg serverside or clientside with js?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am building a lightweight mobile app for people with low-end smartphones, with not so great mobile connections.

Using svg icons in html, one page might have 10-20 of these, making a download of about 5kb-20kb just to transfer the svg icon code alone.

We need to use code, because the icons need to be changeable, e.g stroke, colour. Otherwise .svg files would be used.

I thought perhaps it might be best to store these duplicated codes into a JS variable, and iterate them once the page is loaded on the client side. This would mean the client would only download the svg code once for each icon, and then it would be up to their phone to put the icon many times throughout the page.

Is this bad practice, relying on the phone to do a task like this? On say a smartphone that is 2 years old, would this be using up to much of their phones resources / memory / cpu on a web app?

The way I add an svg icon is like so:

```
var arrowIconNext = '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"'+
                'width="11.8px" height="46.8px" viewBox="0 0 11.8 46.8" enable-background="new 0 0 11.8 46.8" xml:space="preserve">'+
                '<polyline fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="1.3,1 20.2,24 5.3,46.2 "/>'+
                '</svg>';

$('.content .icon').html(arrowIconNext);
```

This cycles through all the .icons on the page and inserts the svg html.

Comment: It depends. The hardware requirements of SVG depend a lot on the complexity of the SVG. A simple SVG can be rendered by a small mobile CPU in no time, but it is possible to create SVGs which take seconds to render even on a high-end workstation.

Comment: By the way: Did you know that you can style SVGs with CSS?

Comment: @Philipp do you mean you can style SVG html with CSS, or actually style SVG files? I have seen you can style SVG html, but I haven't been able to find anything that lets you style SVG files. If you can, that would be ideal.

Comment: Are you gzipping the icons? Can you edit the question to include a sample icon so we can see how you might simplify it?

Comment: @RobertLongson Ok, I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your boilerplate is unnecessary. The id attribute may well be unnecessary too but it's hard to tell without seeing if you're using it.

```
var arrowIconNext = '<svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"'+
                    'width="11.8px" height="46.8px" viewBox="0 0 11.8 46.8">'+
                    '<polyline fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="1.3,1 20.2,24 5.3,46.2 "/>'+
                    '</svg>';
```

Also gzip all your data and send it to the phone as `Content-Encoding: gzip`

Comment: I'm not using the svg id. Thanks for the stripped down version